# Flexcroll and innerHTML

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, innerhtml

I'm trying to get content from a set of hidden (display:none) divs to display on a main "display" div using innerHTML. That part has no problem. However, flexcroll does not seem to load the moment I change the content of the "display" div using innerHTML, even after calling the updateScrollBars method.

Here is the code in question:

```
function switchdis(IDS) {       
    caredet = document.getElementById('caredet');
    carednew = document.getElementById(IDS).innerHTML;
    caredet.innerHTML = carednew;
    fleXenv.updateScrollBars();
}
```

I'm not too sure what is the problem. It seems to me like the function is called (I can scroll using the mousewheel) but the scrollbar is not appearing at all. For the record, my custom scrollbar works fine on other pages. On another page, I used the method of hiding and unhiding divs to change content within the page; the updateScrollBars() method works there when I call it after unhiding a div.

But somehow with innerHTML it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Additional note. I've tried the above function on one of the example files in flexcroll and the same problem occurs. The content is replaced but the scrollbar disappears.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue.

Realised I was updated the innerHTML of the div with flexcroll applied. If anyone is having similar problems, DO NOT DO THAT. Instead, create another div within the flexcroll master div and change the innerHTML of that div.

Additionally, remember to update your flexcroll scrollbars and optionally shift the scroll position to the top every time the innerHTML of that inner div is changed.